# Loading Javascript for minicart in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, cart, javascript, requirejs, mini-cart

I want to make certain customization in minicart, for that purpose I have created a module which overrides `Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html`.

1. **Overriding html**

I have created a module inside which I have a `requirejs-config.js` file:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html':
                'Anime_Minicart/template/minicart/item/default.html'
        }
    }
};
```

2. My **default.html**

My default.html is a copy of core file except I've added a dropdown next to input field as follows.

```
            mydefault.html
            <input data-bind="attr: {
                   id: 'cart-item-'+item_id+'-qty',
                   'data-cart-item': item_id,
                   'data-item-qty': qty,
                   'data-cart-item-id': product_sku
                   }, value: qty"
                   type="number"
                   size="4"
                   class="item-qty cart-item-qty"
                   maxlength="12"/>
            <select id ='minicart-qty-select'>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
```

I'm pretty **sure** that **core file is overridden** by my file since I get to see the mydefault.html text on output.

3. **Adding a Javascript file that loads in every page.**

For this purpose I have created my custom theme and configured it through backend. I have created `main.js` file in location `app/design/frontend/Anime/Mytheme/web/js`, which needs to load in every page.

```
define([
  "jquery"
], 
function($) {
  "use strict";


    $( "#minicart-qty-select").change(function() {
        var currentValue = $('.cart-item-qty').val();
        var selectedValue = $('#minicart-qty-select:selected').val();

        console.log(currentValue , selectedValue);
        alert($('.cart-item-qty').val());
    });
    console.log('Hola');
    console.log($('.cart-item-qty').val());

});
```

4. **Configure magento to load `main.js`**
   Since Magento is configuration based framework we have to explicitly configure it to load `main.js` in whole site. I did that using `requirejs-config.js` in my theme as follows:

> var config = {
>
> // When load 'requirejs' always load the following files also
>   deps: [
>       "js/main"   ]
>
> };

5. **Output**
   My `main.js` file is loaded in every page. And it outputs

> Hola 
>   undefined
>
> Since **Hola** is logged it is confirmed that **custom js file is
>   loaded**. But undefined value in second line makes me think that the
>   **minicart element is not loaded when page is refreshed.**

**On changing the values in dropdown the change event is not triggered
since neither alert nor console.log outputs anything.**

This concludes that my javascript file does not have effect for minicart. So what should be the right way to load javascript for minicart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **on** jquery function instead **change** event, because content of the minicart item is loading via ajax, after page loading.

```
$('#minicart-content-wrapper').on('change', '#minicart-qty-select', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

I hope it'll help.

Comment: Hello, It seem to work, could you elaborate why this particular selector and event working and not mine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your selector on change event of jquery.

```
$( document).on("change","#minicart-qty-select",function() {
    var currentValue = $('.cart-item-qty').val();
    var selectedValue = $('#minicart-qty-select:selected').val();

    console.log(currentValue , selectedValue);
    alert($('.cart-item-qty').val());
});
```

minicart object generate using ko js and once ko js render complete they got minicart-qty-select object. so you need to use **on** function of jquery.

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh, similar solution was suggested by Evgeny, so I had to select his answer. You have been so helpful.